# Hyper-V get connected machine hostname / ip

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, powershell, hyper-v, windows-server

Is there a method to view details of the host connected to a given Hyper-V VM? Note, this is via the Virtual Machine Connection window NOT RDP.

POWERSHELL >> Get-VM (Not seeming to have the functionality I need)

EDIT:
So I want to be able to monitor the active connection to 'Running' machines. Specifically see which host is accessing the VM.

Comment: Assuming the VM is using NAT, then it is a different subnet. Generally we should know the host sponsoring the VM so get the details that way. You can try a bridged connection (external in Hyper-V) and use ipconfig /all